# Setting up a DLL for registration-free COM Interop with C# / Managed code

Tags: c++, .net, com, interop, com-interop

I am new to COM and have to create a COM wrapper for a C++ dll, to make some functionality in it accessible for managed code.  I mainly followed [this tutorial on code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8745/A-Beginner-tutorial-for-writing-simple-COM-ATL-DLL) to create a COM ATL dll. I created a post-build-step that calls tlbimp.exe on the COM dll to create the wrapping.

Adding a reference to the dll that tlbimp.exe creates works, and I get code completion for methods on my COM dll, and can compile managed code that uses that dll. However, running that code leads to the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory 
for component with CLSID {FD6F73D2-0208-455A-953A-C911EC2CAEAB} failed due to the following error: 
80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
//...
```

If I understand this exception and the documentation on MSDN correctly, the next step would be to set up the 'registration-free' part of registration-free COM interop. I have looked at various guides such as [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx) and [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1h056h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but I still don't understand what I have to do.

So my question is:

What are the basic steps I need to take to make my newly created .Net-compatible COM dll load without registration?

Do I have to write a manifest for my .Net app that uses the COM dll?
Do I have to write a manifest for my COM dll? Or the DLL that tblimp.exe generates from it?

Comment: That tutorial is a bit old. Just add the reference to your COM DLL in your .NET project. Then make sure the "Isolated" property is ON for the added reference in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: Could you tell me where can I find the 'Isolated' property in VS2012/3?

Comment: This property does not exist here: http://i44.tinypic.com/2luooq8.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you don't see the `Isolated` property in Solution Explorer, because you manually generated the Interop assembly with tlmbimp.exe, then added it to the project.

Don't do that. Remove that existing reference, then add a new one, where you'd browse for the original unmanaged COM DLL. In Reference Manager, Click `COM` at the left, click `Browse` button, then browse for and select your unmanaged COM DLL. Visual Studio will do the rest.

Comment: Thanks, but VS2012 doesn't allow me to add it the unmanaged COM dll. In a related answer, I've found [this link you posted](http://qualapps.blogspot.ch/2007/06/isolated-com.html). But this also doesn't work, it leads to build errors related to me.exe (Error 31).

Comment: @Wilbert, interesting, I did that many times with VS2012. What error does VS report to you when it fails adding it?

Comment: I accepted the answer for this, but created a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332389/how-to-create-a-helloworld-com-interop-in-visual-studio-2012). I guess I did something else wrong.