# Unable to run a very simple COM client

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, com, com-interop

I'm getting various errors when I try to run a very simple COM client for a very simple COM server that I wrote in C++. The COM server is written in C++ and only has a single method "GetSomeString". I built the ocx of the COM server, registered it using regsrv32, and referenced it from the following C# console application:

```cs
using MySimpleActivexControlLib;

namespace SimpleConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var c = new MySimpleActivexControlLib.MySimpleActivexControl();
            c.GetSomeString();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

I tried to use the component from a C++ console app, and got another error:

> ... Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x002bf5e4
>   ...

The full code can be viewed [here](https://bitbucket.org/johnnyw3/simple-com-app/src).
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using a debugger to see why the exception is being raised?

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks for your response. In the C# console, once the exception is raised this is the top of the run stack:
1. mscorlib.dll!System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(string memberName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags flags, object target, int[] aWrapperTypes, ref System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.MessageData msgData) + 0x183 bytes
2. [Native to Managed Transition]
3. [Managed to Native Transition]  
4. SimpleConsoleApp.exe!SimpleConsoleApp.Program.Main(string[] args) Line 11 + 0x9 bytes C#
Edit: sorry for the bad formatting, I'm trying to format the stack frames more sanely.

Comment: I also tried to run a clean installation of Windows 7 on VirtualBox, then install VS 2010 (as the only software installation), and I still get the same errors.

Comment: The method returned `E_UNEXPECTED`. You need to debug the C++ server to see why it is returning `E_UNEXPECTED`. Or debug the console application to see why it is raising `_com_error`.

Comment: I can't step into the relevant line with the debugger (I immediately get the exception). From the name of the function at the top of the call stack (System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember), I suspect that the error is returned before the C++ server is accessed.
Oh, and both the COM server and client are in the same VC solution, and the symbols for the server are loaded when I start debugging the client.

Comment: If you can't step in, then set breakpoints at key points, like your C++ object's constructor or its GetSomeString method.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I tried that to no avail. I'm not able to step into any source code in the call to GetSomeString.

Comment: Then hard-code a call to `DebugBreak`. Be creative. I'm not going to hand-hold you through this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It certainly depends on what's inside the ActiveX control, but you haven't shown any code of that.

E.g., the control may require an STA thread to run on and be properly hosted by an ActiveX-friendly container, which is not what your test console application does. Try it from a WinForms application:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AxSimpleActiveXControlLib;

class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var c = new AxSimpleActiveXControlLib.AxSimpleActiveXControl();

        var form = new Form
        {
            Controls = { c }
        };

        form.Load += (s, e) => MessageBox.Show(c.GetSomeNumber().ToString());

        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

This may also help:

[How to create a HelloWorld COM Interop in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21332389/1768303)

**Updated**, when you add a reference to an MFC ActiveX control, you should either add it via the Visual Studio WinForms toolbox, or use `AxImp.exe` tool:

```
AxImp.exe SimpleActiveXControl.ocx
```

This way, it will generate `AxSimpleActiveXControlLib.dll` and `SimpleActiveXControlLib.dll`. The former will contain the `System.Windows.Forms.Control`-derived wrapper for you ActiveX control. Add both to your project, then try the code I posted above (updated based on the source code you posted).

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I created the Activex Control using VS 2010 by creating a new "MFC ActiveX Control" project with the default settings, and then adding a single method to the control using class view -> right click on the IDL file -> add method. Do you need more details? I can add the code, but it's 99% boilerplate from the creation of the project in VS.

Comment: @JohnnyW, what happens when you test it with WinForms like I proposed? Also, what does exactly GetSomeString look like?

Comment: I tried to use what you proposed, but I'm getting a compilation error:
"cannot convert from 'SimpleActiveXControlLib.SimpleActiveXControl' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'"