# Building a DLL project to be registration free

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll, com

I have a project that is built with C#(upper layer) that uses COM (C++) dll. Currently it registers the dll upon installation. Is there anyway to configure the project so the dll doesn't need to be registered each time. I am trying to support multiple versions of the software without installing/uninstalling the dll.

Comment: This might be a good place to start: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx

Comment: Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21335520/1768303) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21330437/1768303).